# How to add an Android widget to my app?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I want to put the Android's Analog Clock in my app, is there a way?

**--update**

Studying [android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) page. It says that

> "App Widgets are miniature application
>   views that can be embedded in other
>   applications (such as the Home
>   screen)"

so, looks like there is a way.

**--update**

Still nothing, read all details of the above page, but found nothing about how to add a widget to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the closest will be adding the analog clock widget to your app

```
<AnalogClock android:id="@+id/AnalogClock01" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"></AnalogClock>
```

Comment: So, for widgets I get from the internet for example, it's not possible?

Comment: I didn't search a lot, but looks like it's not possible.